# Proving that a specific function is $L^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

From Rudin's Real & Complex analysis text:

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$ with $f(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and zero otherwise, if we define $h_c(x)=\sup\{n^cf(nx):n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$, how should I go about trying to show that $h_c\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^1)$ if $c\in(0,1)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You conditions on $f$ imply that $f$ is bounded above by a constant $M$. Note that $h_c$ has support in $[0,1]$, and for $x\in [0,1]$,

$$h_c(x) = \sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \{ n^c f(nx)\}\le M \bigg[\frac{1}{x}\bigg]^c$$

(The reason is that for any $k \in \mathbb N$ so that $kx\le 1$, we have

$$k^c f(nx) \le k^c M. $$

The largest such $k$ is where $k = \bigg[\frac{1}{x}\bigg]$).

As

$$\int_{[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]} \bigg[ \frac{1}{x}\bigg]^c dx = \bigg(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg) n^c = \frac{n^c}{n(n+1)} < \frac{1}{n^{2-c}}$$

the function $F(x) = M \bigg[\frac{1}{x}\bigg]^c$ on $[0,1]$ is in $L^1$ (As $2-c >1$). As $0\le h_c(x) \le F(x)$, we also have $h_c \in L^1$.